# Map() not returning JSX when called through a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to output a bunch of li's while iterating through a map function. The issue is that the code works when directly placed inside the render return statement but stops working if I organize it in a helper function and call the function at the return statement.

**WORKS :**

```
const UserList = (props) => {
  if(props.items.length === 0){
    return (
      <div className="center">
        <h2>No users found.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

return <ul className="users-list">
  {
    props.items.map(user => {
      console.log(user.name);
      return <li>{user.id}</li>   
    })
  }
</ul>
```

**DOESN'T WORK:**

```
const UserList = (props) => {
  if(props.items.length === 0){
    return (
      <div className="center">
        <h2>No users found.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const renderList = () => {
  props.items.map(user => {
    console.log(user.name);
    return <li>{user.id}</li>   
  })
};

return <ul className="users-list">
  {renderList()}
</ul>
```

Comment: `renderList` doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I thought only one return was needed.

Comment: Hi, I dont understand why this question was closed, here we have someone who is struggling to get to grips wtih JSX and how components work and this would have been an oppertunity to point them in the right direction

Comment: I would do some research into how functional components work, because Ideally what you want to do is turn renderList into a functional component. Or perhaps another thing you can do which is commin in react is to put the map function inside curly brackets

Comment: @MaxCarroll agreed. Voted to reopen it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have return statement on your method.

```
const { items } = props; 

const renderList = () => {
  return items.map(user => {
      return <li>{user.id}</li>   
    }
  )
};
```

Or a short version with less code. In arrow functions you don’t need to write down the curly braces and the `return` statement if you only return a result without further processing.

```
const { items } = props; 

const renderList = () => items.map(user => <li>{user.id}</li>);
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
const renderList = () => {
    return props.items.map(user => {
        console.log(user.name);
        return <li>{user.id}</li>   
      }
    )
};
```